# Display two array values in single tableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to display webservies array values  in tableview for each cell i need to display two values  Ex:total ten values mean each cell display 2 values in each row. webservies total value nine means each display two values last cell display one value. how can i achieve this help me. new for development.

Comment: use collection view .It will be easier. set width of collectionViewCell as half of screen width

Comment: need to display in tableview any other solution..

Comment: Its little ambiguous. Are you trying to say that you want to show 2 values(one value from each array of your webservices) in each cell but in the last one only 1 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `cellForRow:` you should send the cell the values from the array at `[yourArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row * 2)]` and `[yourArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row * 2 + 1)]`. so row 6 will get the objects for indexes 12 and 13. 
Also you should always check if the objects exists. something like  - `if (yourArray.count > (indexPath.row * 2))` and `if (yourArray.count > (indexPath.row * 2 + 1))` than send to cell else don't. (than you will get one object in cell when you get odd number of values.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this tutorial for custom cell and design it the way you want:

[Crafting Custom UITableView Cells](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702)

This is the method where you can set the values for the custom cell labels from each array:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom class of `UITableViewCell` say `CustomCell` and add 2 labels to it both occupying half of the space or as per your design what you need. Now say that they are `labelOne` and `labelTwo`. 
From your Controller class you got the array of objects that you need to display in lables. In UITableViewDataSource method use this code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {  
      return (dataArray.count+1)/2;  //This will provide correct row count for odd data set, such as when count is 9
}
```

and use this code to populate cell label text

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
      CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if(cell==nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"customCell"];
    }
      cell.lableOne.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*2]; 
      if((indexPath.row*2)+1 < dataArray.count){ 
         cell.lableTwo.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*2)+1];
      }

      return cell;  
 }
```

Comment: My array count is 3 three means it gets crash          cell.lableTwo.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*2)+1]; this line get crash how can i solve that help me...

Comment: @saravanaa: What is the crash log message, and at what point in code it is crashing?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: I guess you have copy-pasted my code from the answer. I haven't wrote the whole code. Check the updated answer and add the new code in your code. See if that solves the issue.

Comment: if the data Array Count is Odd than is it possible to print odd number Cell ?

Comment: how to use didselect method which the help of this

Answer (score 0):

Using `%` fetch the number of rows for the table view. Then for the last cell if value is null then display blank... you can have a basic logic for that. Take 2 lbls in each cell and display on those lables which contains value in it.