# objective c UItableView make two columns

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i am try to to making two columns in my tableview . i am spend huge time google ,to solve but i am failed, here i am share my code,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    tableData =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hello",@"Hello2",@"Hello3",@"Hello",@"Hello2",@"Hello3", nil];
    tableView=[[UITableView alloc]init];
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,320,600);
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [tableView reloadData];
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];

}
```

for table

```
/*Start tableView */
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath] ;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
     cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


   UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:@"H"];
    label.text = @"Demo";

    label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:@"h2"];
    label.text = @"Demo2";

    return cell;


}
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I think you should use UICollectionView insteadOf tableView https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/

Comment: You can use UICollectionView or you may define a custom view with two columns for tableview cells.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620630/display-two-array-values-in-single-tableview-cell#comment49307626_30620630

Comment: You can create a custom class of UITableViewCell and add two labels as subviews to it's content view. Then you can create the object of this class in your data source method - `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and set the text to individual labels corresponding to both the columns.

Comment: You can create custom cell as well
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Answer (score 1):

You can find several demos for your requirement. I’ve specifically used this library and made some changes according to my requirement. You can do the same and hope it helps you like it did to me.. ;) Here’s a link :

https://github.com/kingiol/XCMultiSortTableView

Answer (score -2):

What about to create one column for the line. But eg.: have in that column two buttons that would invoke some action, you would not rely on:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But on some

```
- (IBAction)doSomething
```

And if you will do some graphic separation, it will look like, you want it to look like