# Is it Possible To Design a TableView as a Grid Style ?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am trying to design a table View just like collection View, for example their is two cell in a every row . . .Found similar solution on https://github.com/scasserly/GridTableView but i can not able to understand the solution and also it isn't working now . .

Comment: It's possible, but it's a bad idea.

Comment: possible.but for grid layout collectionview will be better

Comment: Agreed with above. Why not use collection view? That's what it's for. (But also, as other say, it's of course possible.)

Comment: Done . . . see this  . . http://stackoverflow.com/a/30621585/4125508